# Naming conventions for NotificationHubJobType.ExportRegistrations

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

When running a `NotificationHubJobType.ExportRegistrations` job Azure is creating a directory in the azure storage named by the JobId and it contains an Output.txt file containing the registrations.

I have a bug on my table that is caused by a change in this structure and naming. Before it placed the files in [Hub name]//[Hub name][JobId] where // is a directory with no name. Now it places the files in [Hub name]/[Hub name][JobId], skipping the folder with no name.

To JobId names also have changed, now they start with NH- which they did not do before.

I need to understand how this work, is this something that we have configured or is it a naming standard that has changed internally in azure?

Comment: The directory structure and naming convention have changed recently. Before, the files were placed in [Hub name]//[Hub name][JobId] where // is a directory with no name. Now, the files are placed in [Hub name]/[Hub name][JobId], skipping the folder with no name. The JobId names have also changed, now they start with NH- which they did not do [before](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/notification-hubs/export-modify-registrations-bulk.md)

Comment: @Sampath Is this change documented anywhere?

Comment: At the [completion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/notification-hubs/export-modify-registrations-bulk.md#submit-the-job) of the job, you can inspect the results by looking at the [following](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/tree/main/articles/notification-hubs) files in your output directory:

`/<hub>/<jobid>/Failed.txt
,/<hub>/<jobid>/Output.txt`

Comment: [documented](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/notification-hubs/export-modify-registrations-bulk.md#submit-the-job) reference

Comment: @Sampath I don't see anything there mentioning a change in how the exports are named and placed?

Comment: Before: `<Hub name>/<Hub name><JobId>` After: `<Hub name>/<Hub name><JobId>/Output.txt` Before:` [JobId]` Now: `NH-[JobId]`

Comment: @Sampath Thanks, but I'm asking about if this change is (authoritatively) documented anywhere. Do you work for Azure and have internal knowledge? Or have you seen this behaviour yourself?